# Finding the equation of a line knowing a distance

Tags: geometry

Let $A(0,-1)$ and $B(-2,1)$. Find the equation of a line $d$ which is situated at a distance of $5\sqrt2$ units from the line which is perpendicular on the middle of AB.

I found that the equation of the perpendicular on the middle is $y=x+1$ but I don't know how to find the equation of the lines which are situated at a dinstance of $5\sqrt2$ from this.

Comment: Do you mean that the unknown line is *parallel* to the line perpendicular to $AB$ and is at a distance of $5\sqrt2$ from it?

Comment: It's parallel to the line d' and d' is perpendicular on AB and $M\in d'$, M(-1,0) is the middle of AB.

Comment: Do you know how to find the distance of a line from the origin?

Comment: Will you delete this question again Gaboru?

Comment: No, I won't. Thanks for the answers, I solved it

Comment: And why did you do it yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve found an equation for the perpendicular bisector of $A$ and $B$, which I’ll write in the form $x-y+1=0$. All lines parallel to this one have equations of the form $x-y+c=0$ for some constant $c$ that varies from line to line. Thus, your problem amounts to finding the correct values of $c$. One way to do this is to use the formula for the distance of a line from the origin. For this family of lines, this will give you an expression $d(c)$ that has $c$ as a variable. The distance condition in your problem can then be expressed as $|d(c)-d(1)|=5\sqrt2$, which expands into a simple quadratic equation in $c$.

Answer (score 0):

there is exactly two lines that verfie your question, they are symetric in respect to $d{'}$ to find there equations you just have to find the vectors
 $t^{\pm}=\pm 5\sqrt{2}\vec{AB} /AB$ and find the equation of $d^{'}$ lets say $ax+by+c=0$ then the equation of your lines will be $a(x-t^{\pm}_x)+b(y-t^{\pm}_y)+c=0$

Comment: The equation of d' is y=x+1. So I have to find the lines which are parralel to this and at a distance of $5\sqrt2$... I don't know with vectors.

Comment: ok i will make it simpler, the equation of $d$ has the form $y=x+a$ ( because it is parallel to $d^{'}$) to find $a$ you can use that the distance of $M$ to this ligne is $5\sqrt{2}$ this will give an equation of degree 2 on $a$ and you will find tow possible values of $a$.